# call_user_func() and add_action() to define and call a function outside a class Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi Please see the following code of my class

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    function __construct()
    {

        function test1()
        {
            echo 'hii- test1';
        }
        $this->autoload_function();
    }

    function autoload_function()
    {
        $my_array = array(
            "test1"
        );

        
        foreach ($my_array as $my_function)
        {
            call_user_func($my_function);
        }

    }

}

$var = new MyClass();

?>
```

Here I have to add other values to **$my_array** and then I have to define other function outside this class . I have to do this via add_action. So I modified the code please see below

**my-class.php**

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    function __construct()
    {

        function test1()
        {
            echo 'hii- test1';
        }
        $this->autoload_function();
    }

    function autoload_function()
    {
        $my_array = array(
            "test1"
        );

        apply_filters('modify_array', $my_array);
        foreach ($my_array as $my_function)
        {
            call_user_func($my_function);
        }

    }

}

$var = new MyClass();

?>
```

**my-newpage.php**

```
add_action ('modify_array', 'modify_array_function', 0);


function modify_array_function($my_array){
 array_push($my_array, 'test2')
}

function test2(){
 echo 'hii- test2';
}
```

Here i can see that new value is added to array but i am not sure about where i can write my new function i am getting following error

> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
> class **'MyClass' does not have a method**
> **'test2'**

I want to define  test2() inside my-newpage.php and I am ready to add more action or filter inside my-class.php

I setup everything in a proper way that's why **add_action ('modify_array', 'modify_array_function', 0);** is working .

Please help.

Comment: The reason for `test2` function not being called is because it is out of scope. `call_user_func` can only call the functions that have been defined prior to the call. Since your function is in a separate file which is not included in your class or defined as a function in another autoload class, it is not available for execution.

Comment: Hi i am ready to add more action and filters in my-class.php to over come this.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You need to change your my-newpage.php into a class to be able to access its functions in other classes.

Comment: Also, you should use `add_filter()` instead of `add_action()` and return the new value of your array.

Comment: is it a personal functional test? cause in operation, you don't need to implement such a coding structure, you are just implementing a wp actions system again for yourself. why you just don't use do_action in MyClass and add_action in my-newpage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here i can see that new value is added to array

> I want to define test2() inside my-newpage.php and I am ready to add
> more action or filter inside my-class.php

If you're certain `test2` successfully added to the array and that `test2` was being called from `MyClass::autoload_function()`, then you can *try using an early hook **like [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/)** to define `test2`*, like so:

```php
// Defines the test2() function.
function my_define_test2() {
    function test2(){
        echo 'hii- test2';
    }
}

// Now hook on init to ensure test2() is defined before your main plugin
// is loaded.
add_action( 'init', 'my_define_test2', 1 );
```

See my full answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/401109/137402).